# Get value inside div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I am trying to fetch the value inside div, As there are nested div I am not sure how to get the value.
Here is an example and I want to get "Pennsylvanian" and store it in one variable.

```
<div id="map" onclick="mapzoom()" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0">
  <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane">
  <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
  <div class="leaflet-layer>
  <div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated">
  <div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 78px;">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Boundary_Stratotype_Section_and_Point" target="_blank"> Pennsylvanian
 </a>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only `<a>` in the page you can do this with the help of [`querySelector`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj156-Cl8HqAhXEnFwKHZ3nAYkQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelector&usg=AOvVaw1uS1N41HVMZmZ_hFDVDXGS) and [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) like this:

```js
const anchorTag = document.querySelector("a")
const text = anchorTag.innerText
console.log(text)
```

```html
<div id="map" onclick="mapzoom()" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0">
  <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane">
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
      <div class="leaflet-layer">
        <div class=" leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated ">
          <div class="leaflet-popup-content " style="width: 78px; ">
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Boundary_Stratotype_Section_and_Point " target="_blank "> Pennsylvanian
 </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if you got some other `<a>` you have to assign a unique `id` to it and get its value by that `id`. Then you get the element like before with `document.querySelector("#nameOfId")` or [`document.getElementbyId("nameOfId")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

```js
const anchorTag = document.getElementById("anchorTag")
const text = anchorTag.innerText
console.log(text)
```

```html
<div id="map" onclick="mapzoom()" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0">
  <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane">
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
      <div class="leaflet-layer">
        <div class=" leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated ">
          <div class="leaflet-popup-content " style="width: 78px; ">
            <a id="anchorTag" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Boundary_Stratotype_Section_and_Point " target="_blank "> Pennsylvanian
 </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```